# App get stopped when I call second Activity (Main)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two `Activities`. I saw this code on the internet, but the app get closed after `Splash` finish().

```
public class Splash extends ActionBarActivity {
    private final int DURATION = 3000;
    private Thread mSplashThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mSplashThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(DURATION);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                } finally {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            Main.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }

    };
    mSplashThread.start();
}
```

What do I have to do? I want to show the first `Activity` for 3 seconds, and then I want to go to the second `Activity` named `Main`. Please, help me!

This is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ale.bookoflife" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Main activity

```
package com.ale.bookoflife;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Font path
        String fontPath = "LSANS.ttf";

        // text view label
        TextView OurText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font
        OurText.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

"The app has stopped" is the error, and then it crash.

I get mad, what did I make wrong?

Comment: Which error u get????

Comment: _saw this code on internet_ will get you lots of down votes !

Comment: check your manifest file for the hierarchy of your activities

Comment: Use handler for your requirement

Comment: can you please post error log ?

Comment: If you don't post your logs we can not help you. We need to know exactly what is going wrong

Comment: Try to remove the synchronized block..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
mSplashThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(DURATION);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,
                        Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
mSplashThread.start();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :( App get stopped and closed after the 3 seconds :(

Comment: "Unfortunately, App has been stopped"

Comment: Can you post your Manifest.xml file?

Comment: @Akiko93, check that <activity android:name="<Your Packagename>.Main"  /> id added on your Application Tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: @Akiko93, add  Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,
                        Main.class); in place of Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            Main.class);

Comment: @Akiko93, I think problem in getBaseContext(), please change it.

Comment: Now i checked everything, i add what u sayed, but the app get stopped

Comment: @Akiko93,can you post Main.java file?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do what you want is by using Handler, like:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
// here you write the code or function
             Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,
                        Main.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000); //duration to wait
```

Read more on [Android os handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Simply copy-pasting code from the internet won't work if your activity name in [app manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) is different.

Comment: Doesn't work :( I used my names activity, i copy the code but i used my resources

Comment: What is the meaning of doesn't work... Post some logs , does it crash , what is the code in activity2's `oncreate()`, there are too many factors, you need to be as specific as possible

Answer (score 0):

Well can't debug much since you are not providing us with the log.
Well i think the app is crashing because , your are killing the UI thread.
Try removing the finish statement in the splash activity.